# Can Map block thread upon calling get method if the value is null?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections

Is there an implementation of Map, that blocks the thread upon calling the get(X) method if the value is null (or no entry for the X key) and notifies the thread upon another thread calling the put(X, ) method?